# Can't get response from ipify using fetch in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

In my React app, I want to get the IP address of the user at client side. I intended to use `ipify` for that. When I'm using `'http://api.ipify.org/?format=json'` in the browser, it successfully returns `{"ip":"112.135.11.128"}`, but I can't get the same response when I'm making request through fetch API. What I get is something like below.

[image]

**code:**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const QRDisplay = () => {

    async function getIP(){
        const response = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json');
        const data = await response.json();
        return response.status === 200 ? data : "err"
    }

    useEffect( () => {
        getIP().then(data => console.log(data))
    },[])

    return (
        <>
        </>  
    );
};

export default QRDisplay;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call .json() method to get body.

```
async function getIP(){
    const response = await fetch('http://api.ipify.org/?format=json');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
getIP().then(data => console.log(data);
```

Comment: I also tried this, but got `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still throws the same error. I can't understand why

Comment: I have updated the answer. You may need to check response status before returning data. Also don't forget to change http to https in url if you are planning to deploy this to https site

Comment: I edited the code in my question according to your answer, but still getting the same error..

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to `Ozan Bulut`

```
await fetch('http://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
 /* use data here */
});
```